# Get Mouse click event from Microsoft Chart Control click on data marker

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I have a .net 4.0 point chart in my app.  I would like to capture the mouse click on a data marker.  When the user clicks on a particular point, I'd like to go to the row in the bound table where the data came from.

Is this functionality built-in to the .net chart control?

EDIT:  I found that I may have actually wanted the cursor position value rather than requiring the user to click on a specific data point.  Once I have the cursor location, that value can be used to find the row in the dataset that is closest to the mouse click. I accepted the answer to my original question below as it was a correct answer to what I initially requested.

The solution to my 'real' problem was found in the post by user quinn in the post 
[Showing Mouse Axis Coordinates on Chart Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425122/ms-chart-control-showing-mouse-axis-coordinates)

```
{
    var chartArea = _chart.ChartAreas[0];
    var xValue = chartArea.AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(x);
    var yValue = chartArea.AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(y);
    return new Tuple<double, double>(xValue, yValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataPoint dp in this.Chart1.Series["YourSeriesName"].Points)
    {
        dp.PostBackValue = "#VALX,#VALY";
    }
}
protected void Chart1_Click(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs e)
{
    string[] pointData = e.PostBackValue.Split(',');
    // Add click event code here
}
```

You need to set `OnClick="Chart1_Click"` in `asp:Chart`.
Or if you have multiple series on your chart you can set PostBack on Series directly and pass information about the series.

Comment: I believe the e.PostBackValue.Split should split using the "," delimiter and not the semi-colon ";" delimiter. Probably just a typo, but pointing it out for anyone who stumbles upon this question.